# Markdown not rendering simple link

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

I am working on documentation site using a template that runs on Markdown-Jekyll-Liquid-YAML. Everything works fine but have one niggling issue. There's an FAQ template that shows/hides an answer panel; it's all done in CSS and HTML and it works, too. Except, if I include hyperlinks using the Markdown syntax that works everywhere else, the hyperlinks are not being rendered, simply displayed as raw text. (I tried entering the links in plain HTML format, to no avail.)

Here is the relevant snippet of HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="noCrossRef accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseEight">Is DDOS protection in place?</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseEight" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Yes, basic Azure DDOS defence is provided by default and [Azure DDOS Protection Standard] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ddos-protection-overview) can be activated if required.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

First of all you wrote:

```
[Azure DDOS Protection Standard] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ddos-protection-overview)
```

It should be (without the space between the two parts):

```
[Azure DDOS Protection Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ddos-protection-overview)
```

Second of all you should know that using HTML in a Markdown file is allowed... but it [does not always work very well](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#inline-html). I would use a plain HTML link here:

```
<a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ddos-protection-overview">Azure DDOS Protection Standard</a>
```

To be more precise (thank you Chris):

> Markdown is [explicitly](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) "not processed within block-level HTML tags. E.g., you can’t use Markdown-style `*emphasis*` inside an HTML block.".

Comment: Kramdown can be configured to parse block html through `parse_block_html` configuration variable. https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/

Comment: Thanks! I had spotted the extra whitespace, but that didn't solve it. But reverting to plain HTML, as suggested, does the job. Thanks for the tip.